# Zlib linking problems

Tags: c++, linker, codeblocks, libraries, zlib

I'm using CodeBlocks (the latest version, I'm not sure what that is at the moment)

I'm trying to use fallahn's SFML Tiled map loader, and so far I've successfully statically linked SFML and included the map loader files in my source as well as added it to my search directories, however, I'm having trouble linking zlib (which the map loader uses)

I'm gonna go ahead and walk you through how I linked zlib because I'm not even sure which step I messed up on:

1. obviously, I went on over to http://zlib.net and grabbed the latest version (1.2.8)
2. I unzipped it to my desktop
3. I went into my project's build options and initially i thought "I'll just globally set up my search directories like before" (for SFML and the map loader, there was an 'include' and 'lib' folder, i put 'include' in the compiler search directory, and 'lib' in the linker search directory), except there were no folders named 'include' or 'lib' in the folder that i got from unzipping. This is where I simply included the whole folder I unzipped (I'm pretty sure that's terrible practice but I wasn't sure what else to do)
4. I compiled an example from the Map loader's source files, and got an error along the lines of 'undefined reference to inflate' on 4 different occasions. I already figured at this point that I made an error while linking, so that's when I took to google. Most answers were simply "add -lz" or "link libz"

Well, I don't know what "add -lz" means.. like at all, so I just linked "libz", then my compiler gave me the error "ld.exe cannot find -lz", which led me to the assumption that linking libz and adding -lz are the same thing.

Here are some things I *don't* understand at all, and if you can't explain what they are, please at least explain how to blindly do it:
1. Compiling a library
2. Anything to do with make files, I don't know what they are or what they do at all
3. Adding commands to the project command-line.

Build messages:

C:/Documents and Settings/Brenda/Desktop/sfml-tmxloader-master/src/MapLoaderPrivate.cpp:834: undefined reference to `inflateInit2_'
C:/Documents and Settings/Brenda/Desktop/sfml-tmxloader-master/src/MapLoaderPrivate.cpp:843: undefined reference to`inflate'
C:/Documents and Settings/Brenda/Desktop/sfml-tmxloader-master/src/MapLoaderPrivate.cpp:852: undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
C:/Documents and Settings/Brenda/Desktop/sfml-tmxloader-master/src/MapLoaderPrivate.cpp:881: undefined reference to`inflateEnd'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 10 seconds)
4 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 10 seconds)

Comment: Can you show the link command that you configuration is creating?

Comment: The compiler option -lsomething tells the compiler to go find a file called libsomething.a (or whatever the platform appropriate file extension is), and link with it.

Comment: @woolstar How do I access the configuration that's being created?

Comment: I'm not familiar with codeblocks, but if there's a console or log window where it shows the build commands, you could try grabbing the text from there.

Comment: @woolstar Edited post, check now

Comment: You might benefit from reading up on compiling and using DLLs in general, which (while far from trivial), is exceedingly useful, and will help you with all your future unresolved external/undefined reference troubleshooting.

Comment: @Cameron do you have any suggested readings before I start googling?

Comment: @user: I'm afraid not (I learnt this stuff slowly by trial and error and fragmented web searches). A short list of topics to start research on might be: exporting symbols (__declspec(dllexport/dllimport) in MSVC, nothing special by default with GCC), compiling to a DLL, linking against a DLL (with GCC you may get more results by searching "shared object" instead of DLL, but be aware that shared objects are technically for Linux; Windows uses DLLs exclusively), and static (.lib at compile-time) vs. shared (DLL at runtime with .lib at compile time) linking.

Comment: I am away from my windows machine but these errors looks similar to what I was getting recently. There is flag in zlib command line (I think is) ZLIB_WIN. You may to delete it and build and than these errors could go away.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, that zlib doesn't provide binaries for MinGW directly, they only provide *.lib, *.def and *.dll files, but in order to link with MinGW/GCC, you'll need an *.a file.
Since zlib is a C library the ABI will be identical and thus you can "simply" convert it, for instance with the help of [lib2a](https://code.google.com/p/lib2a/). While this should work, it might still be better to download the source code and build zlib yourself, since it ships with a CMake file, it's rather easy to build.